# Hadoop 3.2.1 localhost: ERROR: You must be a privileged user in order to run a secure service

Tags: hadoop, hadoop3

I am trying to install a simple hadoop setup on Ubuntu 20 on windows WSL. I am able to get NameNode and Yarn running but the Datanodes is failing

Getting the following error while trying to start-dfs.sh

```
hadoopuser@mycompu:~/hadoop$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: You must be a privileged user in order to run a secure service.

pdsh@mycompu: localhost: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting secondary namenodes [mycompu]
```

Only the Namenodes are started.

```
(base) hadoopuser@mycompu:~/hadoop$ jps
3217 NameNode
3546 SecondaryNameNode
3676 Jps
(base) hadoopuser@mycompu:~/hadoop$
```

I think the problem is reffering to this section of the documentation -> https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html#Secure_DataNode

But doesn't say how to disable it. I Also tried changing the ports to non priveledge ports but it errored saying its invalid ports.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok...posting a workaround I found that fixed this issue

I just moved the entire hadoop installation folder 
from under /home/hadoopuser/hadoop to the root /opt/hadoop

and this fixed the issue.

Comment: by which user do you start hdfs service?